# How to align the SKU column in invoice pdf?

Tags: sku, invoice-pdf

In generated pdf for the invoice, I have the name of the products overlapping the SKU column , I have changed some code but I don't really know how to get rid of this problem , if anyone can help me to align the SKU from product's rows, it will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation you might have used a custom module overriding InvoicePdf , plase use this code on your Overriden InvoicePDF page. Or if you didn't override , please paste this code in the below path.

> vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf;

    use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;

    /**
     * Sales Order Invoice PDF model
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    class Invoice extends AbstractPdf
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $_storeManager;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
         */
        protected $_localeResolver;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
         * @param Config $pdfConfig
         * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
         * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
         * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
         * @param array $data
         *
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
            Config $pdfConfig,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
            \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
            parent::__construct(
                $paymentData,
                $string,
                $scopeConfig,
                $filesystem,
                $pdfConfig,
                $pdfTotalFactory,
                $pdfItemsFactory,
                $localeDate,
                $inlineTranslation,
                $addressRenderer,
                $data
            );
        }

        /**
         * Draw header for item table
         *
         * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
         * @return void
         */
        protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
        {
            /* Add table head */
            $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
            $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
            $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
            $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
            $this->y -= 10;
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

            //columns headers
            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

            $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

            $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
            $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
            $this->y -= 20;
        }

        /**
         * Return PDF document
         *
         * @param array|Collection $invoices
         * @return \Zend_Pdf
         */
        public function getPdf($invoices = [])
        {
            $this->_beforeGetPdf();
            $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

            $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
            $this->_setPdf($pdf);
            $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
            $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

            foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
                if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                    $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
                }
                $page = $this->newPage();
                $order = $invoice->getOrder();
                /* Add image */
                $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
                /* Add address */
                $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
                /* Add head */
                $this->insertOrder(
                    $page,
                    $order,
                    $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                        self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        $order->getStoreId()
                    )
                );
                /* Add document text and number */
                $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
                /* Add table */
                $this->_drawHeader($page);
                /* Add body */
                foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* Draw item */
                    $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                    $page = end($pdf->pages);
                }
                /* Add totals */
                $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
                if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                    $this->_localeResolver->revert();
                }
            }
            $this->_afterGetPdf();
            return $pdf;
        }

        /**
         * Create new page and assign to PDF object
         *
         * @param  array $settings
         * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
         */
        public function newPage(array $settings = [])
        {
            /* Add new table head */
            $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
            $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
            $this->y = 800;
            if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
                $this->_drawHeader($page);
            }
            return $page;
        }
    }
```